# I can't change the state value in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React for one month. I am having issue right now to change the boolean false value into true. But I can't assign a value to my state. I fetch the data from API called [dog-api](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/documentation/breed) and assigned to the state called images. whenever i click the image i have to assign a favorite value to true but it never works. Here is my code

`import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { AiOutlineHeart, AiFillHeart } from "react-icons/ai"

const Image = () => {

```
const API_URL = `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images/random/12`

const [images, setImages] = useState([])
const [error, setError] = useState(null)
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true)

const [favouriteDogs, setFavouriteDogs] = useState([])

console.log(images)

const handleFavouriteDogs = (id) => {
    console.log(id)
    setImages((prev) => {
        console.log(prev.id) // It shows undefined always, I can't access items in images array of state
        return prev.id === id ?
            [...prev,
            {
                id: prev.id,
                image: prev.image,
                favourite: true
            }
            ]
            : [...prev]

    })
    console.log(images)
}


useEffect(() => {
    const fetchRandomData = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await fetch(API_URL)
            if (!res.ok) throw Error("Please reload the page")
            const data = await res.json()
            const dataArr = data.message.map((item, i) => (
                {
                    id: i,
                    image: item,
                    favourite: false
                }
            ))
            setImages(dataArr)
            setError(null)
        }
        catch (err) {
            setError(err.message)
        }
        finally {
            setIsLoading(false)
        }
    }
    fetchRandomData()

}, [])

const imagesList = images.map((item) => (
    <div key={item.id} className="image_card">
        <div className='image_holder'>
            <img className="image" src={item.image} alt="dog-img" />
        </div>
        <AiOutlineHeart className='image_icon' onClick={() => { handleFavouriteDogs(item.id) }} />
    </div>
))

return (
    <div className='image_container'>
        {!isLoading ? (!error ? imagesList : error) :
            Loading page...
        }
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Image
`

Here, API works fine and I can log images state in console(It logged an array of items), It shows the array also good. But i can't access items in setImages. It shows undefined always idk why! help with this code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find the item and update the state.

**Example:**

```js
setImages((prev) => {
    const items = [...prev];
    const idx = items.find(e => e.id === id);
    if (idx !== -1) {
        items[idx].favourite = true;
    }
    return items;
})
```

Comment: Thnx for the help bro, I found the solution... i need to give an Id value to items[id] istead of items[idx],  like this....                                                                                                                                              `setImages((prev) => {
    const items = [...prev];
    const idx = items.find(e => e.id === id);
    if (idx !== -1) {
        items[idx.id].favourite = true;
    }
    return items;
})`